# ifort: fpe compiling option on mac M1

Tags: fortran

I have compiled a simple program given in this [LINK](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/fc/10.0.026/doc/main_for/mergedProjects/fpops_for/fortran/fpops_fpew_f.htm) to test the fpe compiling option on my mac M1.

Using ifort fpe.f90 -fpe0 -fp-model strict -g the output is

Underflow:  0.1E-29 * 0.1E-09 =   0.1E-39

Overflow:  0.1E+31 * 0.1E+31 =  Infinity

Div-by-zero: -0.1E+31 / 0.0E+00 = -Infinity

Invalid:  0.0E+00 / 0.0E+00 =       NaN

So apparently the option does not work. The same code compiled in the same way on my Linux machine gives the expected results.

I would like to know the reason of this behavior.

This is the code I have compiled is the following

```
             IMPLICIT NONE
             real*4 res_uflow, res_oflow
             real*4 res_dbyz, res_inv
             real*4 small, big, zero, scale
             small = 1.0e-30
             big   = 1.0e30
             zero  = 0.0
             scale = 1.0e-10
      !      IEEE underflow condition (Underflow Raised)
             res_uflow = small * scale
             write(6,100)"Underflow: ",small, " *", scale, " = ", res_uflow
      !      IEEE overflow condition (Overflow Raised)
             res_oflow = big * big
             write(6,100)"Overflow: ", big, " *", big, " = ", res_oflow
      !      IEEE divide-by-zero condition (Divide by Zero Raised)
             res_dbyz = -big / zero
             write(6,100)"Div-by-zero: ", -big, " /", zero, " = ", res_dbyz
      !      IEEE invalid condition (Invalid Raised)
             res_inv = zero / zero
             write(6,100)"Invalid: ", zero, " /", zero, " = ", res_inv
       100   format(A14,E8.1,A2,E8.1,A2,E10.1)
             end
```

I know it's a run-time option: it's a sort of exception handling in Fortran.
As for the secondo question I have installed ifort on my mac M1 and it works.

Comment: Please show the code. See [mcve]. Please note that the option is for **run-time** exceptions, not for computations done at the compile time.

Comment: ifort works on a Mac M1?  Are you running an emulation layer?

Comment: All your computations shown in your code can be done at compile time. Therefore, the runtime exceptions may not do anything. Also, as steve pointed out, if you run the code in some emulation layer on a different CPU architecture, the FPE may not work as expected. Tell us what version of the compiler you have. Run `ifort -v`.